# How to find out if an item in a QTreeWidget is dropped on or above/below an item in PySide 1.0.9?

Tags: python, pyside

I have a simple `QTreeWidget` and have reimplemented `dropEvent()`. With `self.itemAt(event.pos())` I can get the item on which something will be dropped, but how can I find out if something is dropped on an item or above/below it? QAbstractItemView has the function `dropIndicatorPosition()`, but it's not accessible in `QTreeWidget` in PySide 1.0.9 and Python 2.6.5.

I have no problem with the code below in Python 2.7.17 and PySide 1.2.4., but in Python 2.6.5 and PySide 1.0.9 I get the following: `AttributeError: 'SimpleTreeWidget' object has no attribute 'dropIndicatorPosition'`

Is there any way to get the `dropIndicatorPosition` in PySide 1.0.9 and Python 2.6.5 inside `dropEvent()` of a `QTreeWidget` or is there any other way to get that information inside `dropEvent()`?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class SimpleTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setItemsExpandable(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setHeaderLabels(("A", "B"))

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        itemToDropIn = self.itemAt(event.pos())
        dropInidcatorPosition = self.dropIndicatorPosition()

        print dropInidcatorPosition

        super(SimpleTreeWidget, self).dropEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tree = SimpleTreeWidget()

    tree.addTopLevelItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["A"]))
    tree.addTopLevelItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["B"]))
    tree.addTopLevelItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["C"]))

    tree.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed, that `QtGui.QAbstractItemView.dropIndicatorPosition` returns the same `AttributeError`. So it's not an issue with `QTreeWidget` specifically. However according to the documentation for PySide 1.0.7 it should be available: https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.dropIndicatorPosition

I'm writing a plugin for multiple versions of a software called Nuke. All of them come with different versions of PySide. In older versions I get the `AttributeError`. In newer versions it works just fine. Maybe it's an issue with the specific version of PySide in that software? Because according to the documentations `dropIndicatorPosition()` should be available in all the PySide versions I use. If so, is there another way to get the information where an item is dropped?

Comment: What is the output of `from PySide.QtCore import qVersion; print('Qt version', qVersion())` in both python?

Comment: @eyllanesc
For the setup Python 2.6.5 and PySide 1.0.9 that gives me the AttributeError I get: Qt version 4.7.2
For the setup Python 2.7.17 and PySide 1.2.4 I get: Qt version 4.8.7